# Rotation Transition to rotate anticlockwise flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I have this code that makes the icon rotate clockwise. I want to make it rotate anticlockwise. how can I do that?

```
    animationController =
    AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 3))
      ..repeat(reverse: true);

RotationTransition(
            turns: animationController,
            child: Icon(Icons.settings_sharp),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
          )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Concerning `RotationTransition` widget rotation direction is manipulated by [turns](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RotationTransition/turns.html) property.**

*When widget rotates clockwise controllers value goes from 0.0 to 1.0.*

*To rotate in opposite direction you need value to go from 1.0. to 0.0.*

To achieve that, you can set up Tween:

```dart
final Tween<double> turnsTween = Tween<double>(
    begin: 1,
    end: 0,
  );
```

And animate this tween in `turns` property with any `AnimationController` you need:

```dart
child: RotationTransition(
    turns: turnsTween.animate(_controller),
    ...
```

Sample result and code to reproduce:

[image]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
/// AnimationControllers can be created with `vsync: this` because of TickerProviderStateMixin.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController _controller = AnimationController(
    duration: const Duration(seconds: 4),
    vsync: this,
  )..repeat();

  final Tween<double> turnsTween = Tween<double>(
    begin: 1,
    end: 0,
  );

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RotationTransition(
          turns: turnsTween.animate(_controller),
          child: const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: FlutterLogo(size: 150.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add in an AnimationBuilder and Animation object and set the end Tween property to negative.

Also, It looked like you were attempting to have the widget reverse rotation upon completion in a cycle? If so, I added in the code for that too if it helps :)

For example:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    _controller =
    AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 3))
    
//To have the widget change rotation direction upon completion
..addStatusListener((status) {
      if(status == AnimationStatus.completed)
      _controller.reverse();
      if(status == AnimationStatus.dismissed){
        _controller.forward();
      }
    });


  _animTurn = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: -1.0).animate(_controller);

    
    _controller.forward();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _controller,
        builder: (context, child) {
          return
          RotationTransition(
            turns: _animTurn,
            child: Icon(Icons.settings_sharp,size: 100,),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
          );
        });
  }
}
```